# Pick $n+2$ integers from a set of $2n-1$. Prove that the sum of $2$ of the selected integers will be equal to one of the selected numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I want to prove that if we select $n+2$ integers from a set of $\{1, 2, 3,..., 2n−1\}$, then the sum of $2$ of the selected will be equal to one of the numbers we selected.

I understand that i can solve this with Pigeonhole Principle but i don't know how.

I also want to find a subset of $\{1, 2, 3,..., 2n−1\}$ with $n+1$ items which won't have  that ability (if we add $2$ of those $n+1$ items the result won't be in subset). I guess that will be easy if i prove the first part but right know i don't understand  how should i proceed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let the largest number selected be $k$. How many pairs sum up to $k$?

> There are $\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor $ pairs that sum up to $k$.

---

Even with $n+1$ items out of $\{2n-1\}$, you can still find a pair that sum, via the above argument:

Suppose we picked $n+1$ items out of $\{2n-1\}$.
Let $ k \leq 2n-1$ be the largest element.
Consider the $\lfloor \frac{k}{k}\rfloor \leq n-1$ pairs $(1, k-1), (2, k-2), \ldots (\lfloor \frac{k}{k}\rfloor, \lceil \frac{k}{k}\rceil)$.
Since we picked $n$ items out of these, by the Pigeonhole principle, some hole contains 2 pigeons, whose sum is $k$.

---

Conversely, the $n$ items $\{n-1, n, \ldots, 2n-2\}$ do not have any pair that sum to another element. The set $\{n, \ldots, 2n-2, 2n-1\}$ also works.

Comment: Are you sure about that because the second part of the question is that with n+1 items the sum won't be in the subset and i should find that subset..

Comment: Can you find such a subset for any $n$? I suspect that the problem was meant to be $2n+1$.

Comment: The question is from a book ,unfortunetly is not in English so i can't tell you which one :( . It's a university book. They use that book for years so i think if it was a typo they should have find it out by now . I am not 100% sure though

Comment: Is the second part also written in the book? Or are you just trying to find the strongest bound?

Comment: It is i included a screenshot but as i said everything will be Greek to you because it's in Greek  https://imgur.com/a/WvprxLt

Comment: It turns out that the question was wrong. It was meant to be 2n+1. I knew how to solve it for 2n+1 (the way you did) but i thought i was missing something. Thanks a lot for your help